# Get the count sum of an associated model in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, count, nested, associations

This is a little bit hard to explain, so I'll try to be as clear as possible.

In my CakePHP project, suppose I have a model called `Country`, and `Country` has a `hasMany` association to `Region`. Now, the `Region` also has a `hasMany` association to `User`, while the country does not (as the `Region`s can be switched to another country sometime, so associating users to the `Country` with a foreign key would not be an option).

So, right now, my SQL would look basically like this: (Portions only)

```
users: id int(16); region_id int(16);
regions: id int(16); country_id int(16);
countries: id int(16);
```

What I want to do is find a function, or something like `counterCache` in CakePHP, that I can access through the Countries model and get the count of `User` in a `Region` that belongs to a `Country`. I know that I can just get [User][Country], loop through regions and count it, but is there a cached method for this that (preferably) doesn't require extra code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use counterCache on Region, and virtualField('population'=>'SUM(Region.user_count')) (that's just pseudo code!) on Country.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with find('count', 'recursive'=>2) method

You can find the docs [here](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1020/find-count):

Comment: Yes, but that can only get me for one region. Adding the sum is what I'm trying *not* to do. Is there a method that does it, for *all* regions, that belong to a country?

Comment: what about http://book.cakephp.org/view/1033/counterCache-Cache-your-count ? there is eben a behavior out there which should be even more powerful.

Comment: try setting the 'recursive' parameter to 2. I have not used it with count, but it works with find('first') to get the objects of a second level relationship.

    find ('count', array('recursive'=>2));

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1063/recursive